# Is the minimum of two additively separable functions also separable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

For topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, consider the space

$$\tag{1}\mathfrak{S}:=\{(x,y)\mapsto f(x) + g(y) \mid (f,g)\in C(X)\times C(Y)\} \subset C(X\times Y)$$

of 'additively separable' [$\mathbb{R}$-valued] functions. Further, declare for any two $\varphi_1, \varphi_2\in\mathfrak{S}$ their *pointwise minimum*
$$\tag{2}\varphi_1\wedge\varphi_2:=[(x,y)\mapsto \min(\varphi_1(x,y), \varphi_2(x,y))]\in C(X\times Y).$$

**Question:** Is $\mathfrak{S}$ closed under $\wedge$, that is do we have that

$$\tag{3}\wedge \, : \, \mathfrak{S}\times\mathfrak{S} \,\rightarrow\, \mathfrak{S}\ \ ?$$

Comment: **Hint:** Notice that if $\varphi$ is additively seperable, then for all $x_0\in X$, $(x,y)\mapsto \varphi(x,y)-\varphi(x_0,y)$ only depends on $x$. Does this stay true for any $\varphi_1 \wedge\varphi_2$? (btw, I think you meant $\min(\varphi_1(x,y),\varphi_2(x,y))$ in (2))

Answer (score 1):

As Spintoo hinted at in the comments, the answer to this question is trivially negative:

As a counterexample, consider $X=Y=[0,1]$ and let $\varphi_1(x,y)=x$ and $\varphi_2(x,y)=y^2$.

Clearly, $\varphi_1, \varphi_2\in\mathfrak{S}$. If $\phi:=\varphi_1\wedge\varphi_2\in\mathfrak{S}$, then $\eta(x,y):=\phi(x,y) - \phi(0,y)$ would need to depend on $x$ only. However, $\eta(x,y) = y^2$.